# zod "optional()" but disallow undefined value

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have a following [zod](https://zod.dev/) example:

```js
const objectSchema = z.object({
  optional: z.string().optional(),
  other: z.string(),
});
// the current default behavior: 
  objectSchema({ other: "other" }) //pass.
  objectSchema({ optional: undefined, other: "other" }) // pass
  objectSchema({ optional: "str", other: "other" }) // pass
```

In typescript, optional field `key?: string` will be converted to `key?: string | undefined`. But it's strictly different during the runtime check.
The previous one during the runtime check could be interpreted as the `optional` must be `string` if it exists, hence `optional: undefined` is an invalid input.

So, is there any way I can do with zod that makes the `undefined` an invalid input.

hence

```js
  objectSchema({ other: "other" }) //pass.
  objectSchema({ optional: undefined, other: "other" }) // fail
  objectSchema({ optional: "str", other: "other" }) // pass
```

That's my current attempt, which is fine if there is only one optional field, but it starts to become extremely messy and unusable `(z.object().or().or().or()), basically (the number of optional field)^2 permutation`.

```js
const objectSchema = z.object({
  optional: z.string(),
  other: z.string(),
}).strict().or(z.object({
  other: z.string(),
}).strict());
```

Comment: What is your use case for differentiating between `optional` not being present and being present with an `undefined` value?

Comment: I believe there's a TS config option to make `key?: type` different to `key: undefined`, in the way you are asking about. Something about "strict optional" or "exact optional". Maybe that's what you need?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes yep, but more for `zod` itself, since the typescript is generated from the `zod`, and the runtime check is following the ts definition, which allows undefined value for that key. I don't need the `optional()` if there is a correct way to handle it.

Comment: @emeraldsanto sorry, im missing your question? `key: undefined` just cannot be the valid value for many places during the runtime, we cannot expect that piece of data with undefined value will be automatically handled it further down. If zod as a runtime check wouldn't handle this case then I might need to handle it by myself, but maybe there is a way to do it, or I misuse `optional()`?

Comment: @Yunhai Oh, I misread. I thought Zod was performing the check as you wanted but the types didn't correspond.

Comment: There isn't really any practical difference between `{a:...}` and `{a:..., b:undefined}` (in both cases, trying to resolve `b` yields undefined). What _actual thing_ are you trying to add zod typing for here? What's your use case?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , I was trying to either `raise a error` for the undefined value, which sounds impossible based on what you said. Or strip the `b` key away during the parse, either way is fine. Just don't include the `b: undefined` at the end. This might sounds straight forward in this simple case, but it's quite common we have nested object with optional field. then zod will omit a bunch of undefined based on the `optional()` depending on the input. Then it's just not so useful as a validator. Hope you can understand what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: No, I mean "what real thing are you working with that requires this kind of typing", what's your actual real life use-case? (and can you please add that into your post?)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans If I understand your question correctly. `obj = { optionalField?: string }` will be used after the validation. But in some of later usages, the ``undefined` value is not acceptable.  Then for some of codes like `...(obj)`, the `optionalField: undefined` can be passed in accidently. Then I need to hard pick obj.optionalField to check if it's not `undefined`. Basically as @DarrylNoakes said, the typescript "lies" here in static time. I think I specifically mention the subtle difference in my question.  Maybe it's not clear enough?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not sure adding that context is useful. It's just zod will bypass `undefined` with `optional()`, but in many places the `undefined` is unwelcome.

Comment: In terms of plain _property access_, `{}` and `{ foo: undefined }` are the same. If spread, however, `foo` would override a previously defined `foo` property if this object was spread after. The main difference I see is when using `in`/`hasOwnProperty`/`hasOwn` and such, as the property is then _present_, but has a value of `undefined`.

Comment: For completeness, the TS config option is [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes): "Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding undefined."

Comment: @Yunhai Would it be satisfactory to allow the property to be `undefined` when parsing, but have it stripped from the output? So `{ optional: undefined, other: "str" }` parses successfully, but the result is `{ other: "str" }`. I.e., is it de facto an incorrect input, or just a requirement for later code the processes the result?

Comment: I don't think outright disallowing is possible with Zod. It appears to read the keys specified and pass the values to the lower levels, which means the given value will always be `undefined`; i.e., there is apparently no way to tell the difference between a key being not present or it being set to `undefined`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes just like what you said, it's impossible for zod to do it. There is a context behind it. I will later add my answer later based on the zod collaborator's explanation. I got an answer from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based the answer from the `zod` discord community/github collaborator.

`zod` is strictly following the current `typescript` behavior.

 Typescript cannot distinguish the runtime difference between

```
// key is either missing or key exists with type string, cannot be `undefined`
type object {
 key?: string;
}
```

and (in fact the first one will be converted to the second one)

```
// key may or may not exist with the type string or undefined.
type object {
 key?: string | undefined;
}
```

Hence, if you want to strictly enforce the first behavior in runtime, you need to explicitly remove undefined key by yourself. There is no such a shortcut from `zod`.

```
 if (key in object && typeof obj.key === "undefined") { 
   delete obj.key 
 }
```